# Can the sum of infinitely many zero amplitude sinusoids converge to any function?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I've read this in a post here (can't remember which - might even have been a comment) that I thought that was the most ridiculous thing I have ever heard.

Can someone illustrate mathematically that this operation is indeed possible or impossible?

Note:

Actually when I think about it, the comment was about how as amplitudes of all sinusoids converged to zero...something around that ball park

Comment: $f(x)=0$ since 0*sin ax is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "zero amplitude sinusoid" isn't a sinusoid at all. It is a straight line, and the function is equal to zero everywhere, i.e. $\forall x: f(x) = 0$. This means that if $f_n$ is one such function, then

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 0 = 0,$$
meaning that the only function that the sum of infinitely many zero amplitude sinusoids can converge to is the constant zero function.

---

Even if the amplitudes of all sinusoids converges to zero, the answer will be no. We would have $f_n(x) = a_n\sin x$ where $a_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, but that means that for $xk=\pi k$ for any natural number $k\in\mathbb N$, you would still have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x_k) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 0 = 0$$

and indeed, you can show that any function that is the sum of $a_n \sin x$ is actually equal to $$\sin x \cdot\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\right)$$ and so a sinusoid itself.

---

If you really want to approximate functions using trigonometric functions, you will have to start changing not only the amplitudes, but the frequencies of the functions. For example, you *can* approximate (the convergence is uniform) any function on $[0,1]$ using only functions $$\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}{k}\right), \cos\left(\frac{2\pi x}{k}\right), k\in\mathbb N$$

Comment: what if the amplitude of each sinusoid was eplison small, so small that they are almost zero?

Comment: @ProjectBacklog I just finished my edit to answer that question as well.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to allow non-fixed frequencies? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series

Comment: @RobinSaunders That is what the last part of my answer also says, thank you for the link.

Comment: Sorry, I posted before I saw that you had added that.